# Trivial equation but with integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let's consider the following equation:

$$\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt = K$$

where $a, K \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $a, K$ and the function $f$ are known and that the equation should be used to determine $x$.

$$\displaystyle \left[ F(t) \right]_a^x = K$$

where $F(t)$ is the antiderivative of $f(t)$ will provide a - maybe trascendent - equation with $x$ as unknown.

Is this the standard way to solve such problems? Or is there another way?

Sorry if the question could seem trivial. I tried to search "integral equations"; anyway, this one seems to be different, because the unknown is not $f$, but one of the integration extrema.

Comment: I don't see another way to solve this problem.

Comment: There isn't a particularly interesting way to solve this because it simplifies down to just doing some alegbra.  It's much more interesting if f is unknown.

Comment: I agree, this is the way. There is however the addon that this equation may not be uniquely solved by $x$. Consider the case where $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and $a,K=0$. Then $F(x)=\sin(x)$ and we have that $x=2\pi n$, with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @TimHuijgens Yes, sure, I did not write an example but sometimes there can be multiple values for $x$.